# Don't match if a particular query parameter exists

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex which would only match if there is not `cart=1` query paramter there in the URL.

Url will necessarily have `/product/somethign-asda-asdsa-da/?param1=1231&param2=asdas`
here it should'nt have `cart=1`.

Regex I have come up with : `\/product\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/(.*[cart=1]+)`

My progress is here : https://regexr.com/609f3

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead `\/product\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/(?!.*cart=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your regex turning this part `(.*[cart=1]+)` (which is a capture group matching till the and of the line and then matches one of `c` `a` `r` `t` `=` or `1`) into a negative lookahead `(?!` asserting not cart=1 to the right.

```
\/product\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/(?!.*cart=1)
```